# How do I swap a formula to get the opposite value?

Tags: number-theory

I'm guessing this is simple but I am having a hard time working this out. The formula I have is this: **(1-x) / 0.20**. x equals between 0.8 and 1. Example:

- (1-0.8) / 0.20 = 1
- (1-0.9) / 0.20 = 0.5
- (1-1) / 0.20 = 0

What I am trying to do is swap this around so the values would start at 0 and end at 1. How is this done? Also what is this type of problem called?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the formula $\;1-x$, $\;\;0\le x\le 1$.

Comment: I'm looking for something with generic syntax as I'm using it in a programming formula... I can't seem to use ≤